# Accessing root node of XML in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm having trouble accessing the value of the root node of an XML variable in flex.

For example:

```
var X:XML=
  <Message Type="abc">
    Content123
  </Message>
```

I can change the "Type" attribute above with `X.@Type="xyz";`

But how do I change "Content123" to something else?

If the xml document were longer/deeper, I could say something like `X.Entry[11].Cost=2.22;`  But what do I say in this case?  Obviously `X="Content456"` doesn't work...

Comment: Content123 is an xml node itself. It's only a child of Message but not a value or attribute of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
var xml:XML=
  <Message Type="abc">
    Content123
  </Message>;

xml.children()[0] = 'Content456';
```

Answer (score 4):

This is another way, a little safer because you explicitly assign the new value to a text node:

```
var xml:XML=
  <Message Type="abc">
    Content123
  </Message>;

xml.text()[0] = 'Content456';
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have any other child element, you can do `X.setChildren("something else");` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

x.Message  would give the value "abc" in your case.. so u can change it easily i guess!